# Hide Wikipedia Article Feedback

Tags: css

I'm using Stylish for Chrome and I want to edit Wikipedia's css style to not show the "Rate this Page" box at the end of the article. It looks like this:

```
<div id="mw-articlefeedback" class="articleFeedback">

</div>
```

What should I write in the css file to hide this box?

Comment: I have no idea what 'stylish' is; and don't see this as a 'programming question.' Possibly [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) might be a better fit? Though I'd suggest that you're looking for `#mw-articlefeedback { display: none; };`

Comment: @DavidThomas [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) is a Google Chrome app for modifying css styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#mw-articlefeedback {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the size to 0px.

```
#mw-articlefeedback {height:0px; width:0px;}
```

Comment: Why? There are far better ways to hide an element with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you have a Wikipedia account, you could simply go to  My Preferences (at the top) → Appearance → and check the "Don't show the Article feedback widget on pages" box.